# How to filter array of objects using customized input as filters

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Using a multi select dropdown where i have an array of objects where i want to filter it out based on user input such as

```js
[{
        "ServiceArea": "NON-CIO",
        "ManagingDirector": "qwe",
        "Lead": "abc",
        "Manager": "xyz"
        "id":"1",
        "Designation":"COO"
    },
    {
        "ServiceArea": "NON-CIO",
        "ManagingDirector": "dfg",
        "Lead": "hgf",
        "Manager": "lkj"
        "id":"2",
        "Designation":"CTO"
    },
    {
        "ServiceArea": "NON-CIO",
        "ManagingDirector": "out",
        "Lead": "poi",
        "Manager": "uyt",
        "id":"43",
        "Designation":"COO"
    },
    {
        "ServiceArea": "4500-CIO",
        "ManagingDirector": "yhh",
        "Lead": "trr",
        "Manager": "nbb"
        "id":"403",
        "Designation":"CTO"
    }
]
```

Custom user input 1st time-

```js
ServiceArea = ["NON-CIO"]
```

I should be getting first three records.
Second time user inputs

```js
ManagingDirector = ["dgf","qwe"]
```

Here i should be getting first two records.
I am using this function but it seems to append the array not replace.

```js
//airData is main array

array.forEach((item)=>{
 var name = this.airData.filter( el=>el.ManagingDirector == item );
 this.airData.push.apply(this.finalArr,name);
});
```

Comment: Please post ONE ***[mcve]*** of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor you now use just for formatting

Comment: I have mentioned 2 inputs as its a cascading multiselect so i need to filter the array as user selects the options.

Comment: Also why push in a filter? Just use the result of the filtering. And use something like `result = listYouAreFiltering.filter(({ManagingDirector}) => userInputArray.includes(ManagingDirector))`

Comment: If the user input is ["a","s"] i used the loop to find the object and push into the final array. Can you suggest any other method?

Comment: When `array = ["dgf","qwe"]`, you mentioned you should be getting first two records. That looks like a typo. `qwe` is in the first and third objects. And the second object has `dfg` not `dgf`. So, you'll get the first and third objects in that case.

Comment: Edited the question for better understanding. @adiga

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a `filters` object like this

```js
const data = [{ServiceArea:"NON-CIO",ManagingDirector:"qwe",Lead:"abc",Manager:"xyz"},{ServiceArea:"NON-CIO",ManagingDirector:"dfg",Lead:"hgf",Manager:"lkj"},{ServiceArea:"NON-CIO",ManagingDirector:"qwe",Lead:"poi",Manager:"uyt"},{ServiceArea:"4500-CIO",ManagingDirector:"yhh",Lead:"trr",Manager:"nbb"}];

const filters = {
  ServiceArea: ["NON-CIO"],
  ManagingDirector: ["dgf", "qwe"],
  Manager: []
}

const result = data.filter(e =>
  Object.entries(filters).every(([key, vals]) =>
    vals.length === 0 || vals.includes(e[key])))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi, will this handle empty array scenario too. If user decides to lets say remove managingdirector input from UI. The array becomes blank now only servicearea should work.

Comment: @RahulJain: no, you need something like `val.length === 0 || vals.includes...`

Comment: Can you give an example? As i have 6 different arrays where input gets stored and user can anytime deselect or select which will make each array sometimes empty also.

Comment: Aslo if i don't have any value in the beginning  .includes() gives error of does not exist on type unknown

Comment: @RahulJain the snippet is updated with gog's code. Please update the question with your actual examples. There are only 4 properties in each object and you have mentioned there will be 6 different arrays.

Comment: @adiga Updated the data. Using the above snippet i am getting an error `Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'unknown'`. As i need to update the filter object after the user input. How do i declare this in my angular component?

Comment: @RahulJain that's a ts error, you can search for it. There are plenty of examples

Comment: @RahulJain Here's a ts snippet: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkgJSgYwPYCcAmMC8MDewMMAylOgG4CWyUAgulAIYBcMAziOlQHYDmAGiIwAskx5M+vPgBEqjZCAxtO3fkOIAZZphVdpG0eMnkWq6cAC+wND04xMTEK0QoMmANoBdXDA-4yShp6RlYAIgA5AHkIgFoAYTgosIExCSl+OQUldBYwgEcAdygU7SZdMKYAI2QUtJNcsIAPMAAvMMsvAG5gG1Q7EBgAMyoAGxBydjYkNCwAHgBrKDBUIfgZ9wEOfX5vAD5fQmJA6loGZjYPSJiEpLCvQ3qM2XkUHMuwzD4hlJgC4vuj2MfFMfgewjKujBVl6tnsjHYAFdxr5HM4AHQjcbkAAUsBwe2EUSqACs3uioDx9FB2DisRN0OwAJQUijkMA4nEeJZgLYUJijdheJm4QnEYj8wXo0aUvggAAWuBweAADDAAD7qmCS9jo3jIUaIzA0vHc5YwJjsGA81brNxYYVMpmw-rsVAy6WoPg4hHIkBMoA