# How to check multiple null value in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 3 ngModel in my UI which are binded in my angular application. All of them are selected by user using multi select dropdown.

```js
country = ["India", "US"]
state = ["Delhi", "MP","UP"]
city = ["gzb","xyz"]
```

I have a custom filter where i have to filter data based on these responses

```
filter = {
country: this.country,
state: this.state,
city: this.city
}

result = data.filter(e =>
Object.entries(filters).every(([key,vals])=>vals.includes(e[key])))
```

There is a scenario where only country array is there and other 2 are empty. Here my filter will fail. How to check null

Test Data

```
data=[{
"name":"hello",
"gender":"male",
"country":"India",
"state":"Delhi",
"city":"gzb"
}]
```

Comment: Can you update the question with a testdata for `data`?

Comment: Multiple such records just like this.

Comment: @RahulJain in [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74822164/3082296) comment, they have already mentioned that you need to use `vals.length === 0 || vals.includes(...)`. The snippet is updated. What doesn't work in that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the length of the elements of filter.

If the length off that specific node in filter is zero, then there is no point in checking that filter node, simply return true for that case.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const country = ["India", "US"];
// const state = ["Delhi", "MP", "UP"];
const state = [];
const city = ["gzb", "xyz"];
const filter = {
  country,
  state,
  city,
};
const data = [
  {
    name: "hello",
    gender: "male",
    country: "India",
    state: "Delhi",
    city: "gzb",
  },
];
const result = data.filter((e) =>
  Object.entries(filter).every(([key, vals]) => vals.length > 0 ? vals.includes(e[key]) : true)
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works. How can i use this in Angular? All the fields are user input and using this snippet give `Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'unknown'`.

Comment: You can just change the variables to your class variables, you can fix this yourself